# How do I animate the background color of button with multiple classes using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using Foundation to create a new webpage.  On this page, I have this button:

```
<a href="#bottomOfPage" class="small round button" id="viewOurWorkButton">View Our Work</a>
```

I'd like to animate this button by simply changing it's background color and font color.  The problem is, when I try to access the button's properties using the id #viewOurWorkButton, nothing happens.  Here's what I'm trying to do with jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  buttonAnimation();
});

function buttonAnimation() {
  $('#viewOurWorkButton').animate({
          $('#viewOurWorkButton').css({backgroundColor:'#fff', color:'#000'})
        }, 1000, function(){
          $('#viewOurWorkButton').animate({
          $('#viewOurWorkButton').css({backgroundColor:'#000', color:'#FFF'})
        }, 1000, buttonAnimation);
      });
}
```

This also shows this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

I also tried to do the animation on .button but still no effect.  Here is what the .button class looks like:

```
button, .button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 2rem 1.0625rem 2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: #008CBA;
    border-color: #007095;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
}
```

How can I animate the .button properties?

Comment: A _fiddle_ will be handy

Comment: which line of codes does the error refers to?

Comment: $('#viewOurWorkButton').css({backgroundColor:'#fff', color:'#000'}) throws the error

Comment: quotes are missing `$('#viewOurWorkButton').css({'backgroundColor' : '#fff', 'color' : '#000'})`

Comment: Tried it - still have the same error.

Comment: along with `;` at end `$('#viewOurWorkButton').css({'backgroundColor' : '#fff', 'color' : '#000'});` just noticed in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to repeat the `selector` to `animate`, you only need to list the `properties`. And also `animate` supports chaining.

And note that you can use `jQuery` to animate numeric properties, but to animate colors, you'll need `jQuery-ui`.

This seems to work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    buttonAnimation();
});

function buttonAnimation() {
    $('#viewOurWorkButton').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color: '#000'
    }, 1000).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        color: '#FFF'
    }, 1000, buttonAnimation);

}
```

```html
 <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <a href="#bottomOfPage" class="small round button" id="viewOurWorkButton">View Our Work</a>
```

Comment: It's so close!  The text color is working smoothy, but the background color transition is very choppy.  It doesn't fade in out and out smoothy at all.  Might it have to do with the fact that the button has multiple classes on it?

Comment: AH! Figured it out!  This line in the button class was causing the choppiness in the animation: transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;  Why would that cause an issue?

Comment: When you have a transition in the css, as soon as you change the value it'll transition it with according settings. When you use animate, jquery simply changes the value over a certain period of time. It means that each change in value is tranisitioned, which of course gives a weird result. You need to chose between either approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inlcude first jquery UI lib on your page html, then I just modified your jquery code like this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  
  buttonAnimation();

});

  function buttonAnimation() {
 
  $('#viewOurWorkButton')
        .animate({ backgroundColor:'#fff', color:'#000' }, 1000 )
        .animate({ backgroundColor:'#000', color:'#FFF' }, 1000 );
}
```

```css
button, .button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 2rem 1.0625rem 2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: #008CBA;
    border-color: #007095;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a href="#bottomOfPage" class="small round button" id="viewOurWorkButton">View Our Work</a>
```